# search multiple php files, and replace text?

Tags: linux, bash

i have several php files, and there's references to .html files in those.

I need to replace ".html" to ".php"

how can i do this in bash ?

Comment: You'll probably want to double-check the results of this. You wouldn't want, for example, an external link to another *.html file that's a legitimate link to be renamed to PHP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for file in $(find . -name "*.php"); do
    sed "s/\.html/.php/g" $file > $$ && mv $$ $file
done
```

Answer (score 1):

```
find -name '*.php' -exec sed -ie 's:.html:.php:g' {} \;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try sed:

```
find -name "filenamepattern.php" -print0 | xargs -0 sed 's/\.html/\.php/g'
```

Answer (score 0):

GNU find

```
find /path -type f -iname '*.php' -exec sed -i.bak 's/\.html/\.php/g' {} +;
```